# Manipulation with an array using iterators

Tags: c++, iterator

I want to reverse an array of chars using 2 iterators, but i figured out that i entry the loop once and swap() never worked.
`

```
std::vector<char> s = {'a','b','c','d'};
std::vector<char>::iterator it1{s.begin()}, it2{s.end() - 1};
while(it1 < it2){
  swap(it1,it2);
  ++it1;
  --it2;
}
`
```

If i write while(it1 != it2),I will never get out of the loop. Could you explain where the mistake is.

Comment: If you execute your program, step by step, or even write it out on paper in pencil, keeping track of the iterators, it should be trivial to see why the iterators never become equal. Have you tried doing that?

Comment: Dereference the iterators when swapping.

Comment: I used the debugger, but couldn't find a solution

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the std::swap function requires two references. The iterators need to be dereferenced for the swap, as you are swapping the values that the iterators point to, not the iterators themselves.

```
swap(it1, it2);
```

needs to be replaced with

```
swap(*it1, *it2);
```

The rest of your code seems to be fine and without any errors. I haven't used iterators before, but it seems that they behave a lot like pointers. Apologies for any errors as this is my first answer.